# Numpy memory leak?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-leaks, reference-counting

I am debugging a Python application embedded in a C++ program.

When I query an numpy array attribute via `PyObject_GetAttrString` and nicely derefence it (`Py_DECREF`) afterwards, I still see the ref count increasing.
Ref count I trace via `PyObject_CallObject(PySys_GetObject((char*)"gettotalrefcount"), NULL)`

If I replace the numpy array by a standard python list, then ref counts are stable.

A next simple test I did was the following with a python debug build:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 23:07:03) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
[155099 refs]
>>> l = numpy.array([1,2])
[155102 refs]
>>> l
array([1, 2])
[155156 refs]
>>> l
array([1, 2])
[155207 refs]
>>> l
array([1, 2])
[155258 refs]
>>> l
array([1, 2])
[155309 refs]
>>> l   
array([1, 2])
[155360 refs]
```

As you can see the ref count increases continuously, which I did not expect/do not understand.

Anyone a clue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly this https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/6e5f0c1231

Comment: What version of numpy are you using?